# Visual Studio 2015 C++ v141 issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I wonder why it says everything has been installed successfully https://gyazo.com/b1ca547dd693e27c5b937a585ead599f but this still comes up https://gyazo.com/82cb66a73cdbd9dc6b0f630240f4bfa6? I am thankful for any help from anyone since i've been trying to install Visual Studio 2015 for soo many weeks, then i finally found a fix on this forums website, that actually worked, then i got that v141 builds tools error, thanks for reading and send this to your friends if they might know how to fix.

Comment: if someone viewing this question helps i'd be happy :)

Comment: What makes you think we have friends?

Comment: Platform Toolset V141 is from Visual Studio 15 2017 RC not Visual Studio 14 2015.

Comment: The first video I did not have the patients to watch more than 2 minutes. The second picture had a font size that was way too small to read.

Comment: Are you using CMake?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me upon installing Visual Studio Community 2015! I uninstalled and also went through and uninstalled all the older versions of Visual Studio I had on my computer! Next time I installed, the build tools error (among others) was gone! I may have just gotten lucky but it's worth a shot, right?